# Fast Fourier transform for a sequence of complex numbers with arbitrary size

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I want to apply fast Fourier transform for a sequence of complex numbers with length N. N can be anything (not necessarily a power of 2). It seems that Cooley–Tukey algorithm only works for the sequences with length of a power of 2. I was wondering whether exists other algorithms with time complexity of $O(NlogN)$ which works with no restrictions on N?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can always pad the sequence with zeroes until you reach the next power of $2$.

Comment: @Math1000
thanks.

Comment: See also [Bluestein’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform#Bluestein.27s_algorithm).